# Getting time data from user using Python to schedule task 10 mins into the future

Tags: python

Im trying to get Python to check if time given is at least 10 minutes into the future. when entering data, I am always getting back the 'else' clause; `The scheduled time must be at least 10 minutes from now`
Here is the code im working with so far:

```
while len(schedTime) == 0:
        schedTime = raw_input('Scheduled Time (hh:mm): ')

        schedHr = schedTime.split(':')[0]
        schedMi = schedTime.split(':')[1]

        try:
            testTime = int(schedHr)
            testTime = int(schedMi)
        except:
            print 'The scheduled time must be in the format hh:mm)'
            schedTime = ''
            continue

        if int(self.hr) <= int(schedHr) and int(self.mi) + 10 <= int(schedMi):
            pass
        else:
            print 'The scheduled time must be at least 10 minutes from now'
            schedTime = ''
```

Second part of the script a little(lot) further down:

```
 ### Get the current time
    now  = datetime.datetime.now()
    yrF = now.strftime('%Y')
    moF = now.strftime('%m')
    dyF = now.strftime('%d')

    then = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    self.hr = then.strftime('%H')
    self.mi = then.strftime('%M')
```

Comment: I did read about TimeDelta and it would be better to use then what I have. However, I think I would end up rewriting this entire script to do so and right now I can't afford to so. What I presented was just a small snipit of the actual code I am working with. This was givin to me "as-is"

Comment: You would not have to rewrite the entire script, just four lines. I have adapted my original answer to show what changes you need to make.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the datetime library: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html. You can create a two timedelta objects, one for the current moment and one for the scheduled time. Using a substraction, you can see if the scheduled time is less than 10 minutes away from now.

E.g.

```
t1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=self.hr, minutes=self.mi)
t2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=schedHr, minutes=schedMi)
t3 = t2 - t1
if t3.seconds < 600:
    print 'The scheduled time must be at least 10 minutes from now'
    schedTime = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this script, the most glaring is that you are not considering hour roll over.  For example, if time is 5pm and someone puts in 6pm, clause:

```
int(self.hr) <= int(schedHr) and int(self.mi) + 10 <= int(schedMi)
```

will be false since self.mi is 00 and schedMi is 00.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a timedelta object. For instance:

```
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
#read in user_time from command line
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
if user_time < current_time + tdelta:
    print "Something is wrong here buddy"
```